# play scala deployment on heroku

Tags: java, scala, heroku, deployment, playframework

I have downloaded play scala app using this link
https://www.playframework.com/getting-started
and modified the logic according to our requirement. I deployed  app on heroku successfully. But when I accessing website using the url provided by herolu it shows me an application error message something like this

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
```

heroku logs --tail

> 2020-12-24T09:11:44.372725+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=playsample.herokuapp.com request_id=96959eac-dc81-4965-9a2d-61e48bs4fegf fwd="47.9.72.84" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution for this error. I just added heroku plugin in plugin.sbt and declare the name of the heroku app in build.sbt and also specified the host in application.conf file.
For more info try this video to  find in depth solution

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSpfFWvN5s0